# Getting rid of 'for' loops when cattegorizing data by lat and lon

Tags: matlab

I need help getting rid of 'for' loops.  Right now I am looping through a whole bunch of data, looking up its latitude and longitude, and then figuring out what the average value is for each box in the array.  I guess my biggest problem is figuring out how to get rid of the i=1:n and j=1:m loops which allow me to make a grid of my data dispersed into lat and lon boxes.

Note: I am getting 'mu' which is the number of files from another bit of code and I just use the p=length(lat{1,k}) to figure out how long each file is.

```
n=36;
m=72;
counter=zeros(36,72);
sum=zeros(36,72);
average=zeros(36,72);

for k=1:mu
    p=length(lat{1,k});
    for i=1:n
        for j=1:m
            for u=1:p
                if (ge(lat{1,k}(u),i*5-95) && lt(lat{1,k}(u),i*5-90) && ge(lon{1,k}(u),j*5-185) && lt(lon{1,k}(u),j*5-180))
                    if lt(sfc{1,k}(u),0)
                        sfc{1,k}(u)=0;
                    end
                    sum(i,j)= sum(i,j) + sfc{1,k}(u);
                    counter(i,j)= counter(i,j) + 1;
                    average(i,j)= sum(i,j)/counter(i,j);
                end
            end
        end
    end
    average
end
```

Comment: Rather than make us parse your code and infer what it's doing, perhaps you could describe in some detail the format of your data and the operations you wish to do on it.